# The error "personal is not defined" occurs when running Geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to use Geth to set up a local Ethereum test network.
My startup command is: `geth --datadir ./data --nodiscover console 2>>geth.log.`
When I tried to create an account using personal.newAccount("12345"), the terminal reported an error "personal is not defined".

[image: 1]

I tried to add the command `--http --http.api 'web3,eth,net,debug,personal'`to the startup command, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

**Personal Namespace has been deprecated.**
Instead,
create a new user with the **Clef** command.

If you have installed geth, clef should be installed.

```
which clef
>/opt/homebrew/bin/clef
```

or something similar.

To create a new user with clef, create a keystore file. if there is no keystore folder directly under dataDir, create one.

```
mkdir [yourDataDir/keystore]
```

Then run the following command

```
clef newaccount --keystore [yourDataDir/keystore]
```

After typing the command
You will be asked for "ok". Then enter your password. (At least 10 characters).

> Your new key was generated

should appear on the screen.

The key file is generated in the folder specified in
--keystore.

Next, start by specifying the folder where the keystore file generated by the geth command is located.

For example, specify it with the --keystore option as follows.

```
geth --networkid "15" --nodiscover --datadir . / --keystore . /keystore console 2>> . /log/geth_err.log
```

When the prompt starts up.
You can check in prompt

```
eth.accounts
>["0x94c52f891819d46b15d84a05e621f15f20ab307b"]
```

Your user wallet should have increased.

Comment: document is

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-personal